# MirrorStrategy doesn't see GPU - INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to use `MirrorStrategy` to test how the model is distributed. I am using `Estimator` API on Google Colab.

However once I run the code

```
distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute= distribution,
                                model_dir = 'tf_logs/test')
```

I get a warning:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing RunConfig with distribution strategies.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
```

I turn on GPU on Colab:

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
TRUE
```

I also tested it on EC2 instance with several GPUs. Do you know what wrong with this stuff?

As a reference please look and run this [code](https://github.com/shu-yusa/tensorflow-mirrored-strategy-sample/blob/master/cnn_mnist.py).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is only 1 GPU available on colab?

Comment: That's right. But I also checked it on EC2 instance with 2 GPUs.

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: the latest v1.12.0

Comment: OK, it seems to work. The message is quite confusing though.

Comment: Thats strange. Do you have any guesses why this showed up?